# phone number in EditText

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having a form wherein i get user details, in that i have field called phone number and Edit Text to put phone number.

i have feeling that it would be great if that edittext automatically get filled by user phone number.
is there any method which automatically fills user phone number with national code??

below code was posted on stackoverflow i think it might work in some instances can anyone help me for same?

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber() {
  TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
  mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i have feeling that it would be great if that edittext automatically get filled by user phone 
number*
To solve the above problem, your best bet is to use,

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

with the permission added of course

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

But the problem is that the documentation for [getLine1Number()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29) says this method will return null if the number is "unavailable", but it does not say when the number might be unavailable.

*is there any method which automatically fills user phone number with national code??*
To solve this issue, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a direct way to get the user's current country code. But since country codes don't ever change, it is acceptable to hard code a lookup table in your application.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<icc>
    <AF>93</AF>
    <AL>355</AL>
    <DZ>213</DZ>
    <AD>376</AD>
    <AO>244</AO>
    <AQ>672</AQ>
    <AR>54</AR>
    <AM>374</AM>
    <AW>297</AW>
    <AU>61</AU>
    <AT>43</AT>
    <AZ>994</AZ>
    <BH>973</BH>
    <BD>880</BD>
    <BY>375</BY>
    <BE>32</BE>
    <BZ>501</BZ>
    <BJ>229</BJ>
    <BT>975</BT>
    <BO>591</BO>
    <BA>387</BA>
    <BW>267</BW>
    <BR>55</BR>
    <BN>673</BN>
    <BG>359</BG>
    <BF>226</BF>
    <MM>95</MM>
    <BI>257</BI>
    <KH>855</KH>
    <CM>237</CM>
    <CA>1</CA>
    <CV>238</CV>
    <CF>236</CF>
    <TD>235</TD>
    <CL>56</CL>
    <CN>86</CN>
    <CX>61</CX>
    <CC>61</CC>
    <CO>57</CO>
    <KM>269</KM>
    <CG>242</CG>
    <CD>243</CD>
    <CK>682</CK>
    <CR>506</CR>
    <HR>385</HR>
    <CU>53</CU>
    <CY>357</CY>
    <CZ>420</CZ>
    <DK>45</DK>
    <DJ>253</DJ>
    <TL>670</TL>
    <EC>593</EC>
    <EG>20</EG>
    <SV>503</SV>
    <GQ>240</GQ>
    <ER>291</ER>
    <EE>372</EE>
    <ET>251</ET>
    <FK>500</FK>
    <FO>298</FO>
    <FJ>679</FJ>
    <FI>358</FI>
    <FR>33</FR>
    <PF>689</PF>
    <GA>241</GA>
    <GM>220</GM>
    <GE>995</GE>
    <DE>49</DE>
    <GH>233</GH>
    <GI>350</GI>
    <GR>30</GR>
    <GL>299</GL>
    <GT>502</GT>
    <GN>224</GN>
    <GW>245</GW>
    <GY>592</GY>
    <HT>509</HT>
    <HN>504</HN>
    <HK>852</HK>
    <HU>36</HU>
    <IN>91</IN>
    <ID>62</ID>
    <IR>98</IR>
    <IQ>964</IQ>
    <IE>353</IE>
    <IM>44</IM>
    <IL>972</IL>
    <IT>39</IT>
    <CI>225</CI>
    <JP>81</JP>
    <JO>962</JO>
    <KZ>7</KZ>
    <KE>254</KE>
    <KI>686</KI>
    <KW>965</KW>
    <KG>996</KG>
    <LA>856</LA>
    <LV>371</LV>
    <LB>961</LB>
    <LS>266</LS>
    <LR>231</LR>
    <LY>218</LY>
    <LI>423</LI>
    <LT>370</LT>
    <LU>352</LU>
    <MO>853</MO>
    <MK>389</MK>
    <MG>261</MG>
    <MW>265</MW>
    <MY>60</MY>
    <MV>960</MV>
    <ML>223</ML>
    <MT>356</MT>
    <MH>692</MH>
    <MR>222</MR>
    <MU>230</MU>
    <YT>262</YT>
    <MX>52</MX>
    <FM>691</FM>
    <MD>373</MD>
    <MC>377</MC>
    <MN>976</MN>
    <ME>382</ME>
    <MA>212</MA>
    <MZ>258</MZ>
    <NA>264</NA>
    <NR>674</NR>
    <NP>977</NP>
    <NL>31</NL>
    <AN>599</AN>
    <NC>687</NC>
    <NZ>64</NZ>
    <NI>505</NI>
    <NE>227</NE>
    <NG>234</NG>
    <NU>683</NU>
    <KP>850</KP>
    <NO>47</NO>
    <OM>968</OM>
    <PK>92</PK>
    <PW>680</PW>
    <PA>507</PA>
    <PG>675</PG>
    <PY>595</PY>
    <PE>51</PE>
    <PH>63</PH>
    <PN>870</PN>
    <PL>48</PL>
    <PT>351</PT>
    <PR>1</PR>
    <QA>974</QA>
    <RO>40</RO>
    <RU>7</RU>
    <RW>250</RW>
    <BL>590</BL>
    <WS>685</WS>
    <SM>378</SM>
    <ST>239</ST>
    <SA>966</SA>
    <SN>221</SN>
    <RS>381</RS>
    <SC>248</SC>
    <SL>232</SL>
    <SG>65</SG>
    <SK>421</SK>
    <SI>386</SI>
    <SB>677</SB>
    <SO>252</SO>
    <ZA>27</ZA>
    <KR>82</KR>
    <ES>34</ES>
    <LK>94</LK>
    <SH>290</SH>
    <PM>508</PM>
    <SD>249</SD>
    <SR>597</SR>
    <SZ>268</SZ>
    <SE>46</SE>
    <CH>41</CH>
    <SY>963</SY>
    <TW>886</TW>
    <TJ>992</TJ>
    <TZ>255</TZ>
    <TH>66</TH>
    <TG>228</TG>
    <TK>690</TK>
    <TO>676</TO>
    <TN>216</TN>
    <TR>90</TR>
    <TM>993</TM>
    <TV>688</TV>
    <AE>971</AE>
    <UG>256</UG>
    <GB>44</GB>
    <UA>380</UA>
    <UY>598</UY>
    <US>1</US>
    <UZ>998</UZ>
    <VU>678</VU>
    <VA>39</VA>
    <VE>58</VE>
    <VN>84</VN>
    <WF>681</WF>
    <YE>967</YE>
    <ZM>260</ZM>
    <ZW>263</ZW>
</icc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set that phonenumber in your edittext like this edittext.setText(mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number())

Answer (score -1):

There is plenty of questions relating to this.

Your method relies on the phonenumber being stored on the sim, which it rarely is.

The most reliable method is to let users input the number themselves. Though it would not hurt to let the getLine1Number() method try and set the number first.

I have chosen to let my app send a SMS to the number with an unique message, which when received, completes the verification of the input number. The number then finally is stored in a sharedPreference.

This method of course runs short if the user changes sim but if you need to handle that, it could be done by also saving the IMEI so that it can be checked when app starts.

Comment: Do not get the downvote? My answer gives an alternative when getLine1Number() does not give a phonenumber. I would think that is useful.